# c++ how to sign a derived class object base on the value of a same type temp object?

Tags: c++

```
Class Dad{

    public:
        Dad();
        Dad(char v){Dad_value = v;}

    private:
        char Dad_value;
};

class Child :public Dad{

    public:
        Child();
        Child(short v1, short v2, char v):Dad(v){Child_v1 = v1; Child_v2 = v2;}

    private:
        short int Child_v1;
        short int Child_v2;
};

//---------------------------------------

//define a Child array:
Child bd[100]; 

for (int i =0; i<100;i++){

    bd[i] = Child(a,b,c); 

}
```

a b c are read from file，two short and one char. how to sign bd[i]. I tried overload “=”, but how to deal with the part of base class, which is private is Dad class.

thank you.

Comment: Your code should work as written. Compiler-generated assignment operator would do the right thing. What specifically do you feel is the problem?

Comment: Not clear what you asking about. Please rephrase (without using Google Translate). Or maybe give an example of what you would like to achieve in pseudo-code?

Comment: Does "sign" mean "assign"?

Comment: yes, it means assign.... sorry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also declare an `operator=(Dad& other){...}` in your `Dad` class. And then invoke this from your child class. like this:

```
class Child{
  Child& operator=(Child& other){
    Dad::operator=(other);
    //more assignments
  };
```

This is because you declared your `Dad`s variable `private` which means it is not allowed to be modified by anything that is not a `Dad::method()`. Usually when things are private it is with a good reason; ie. you don't need to change it, or there is a nicer way to do so.
If you do want to allow your `Child` to modify `Dad`s variables, you can make the variable `protected` in the `Dad`.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the compiler-generated assignment operator?

Comment: Whatever you think this is solving, it isn't needed for what the OP is apparently asking. The compiler-generated assignment operator should take care of this. As Igor said in general-comment, the code as-is should work, assuming the remaining constructors are properly implemented as-declared.

Comment: thanks. because I need to declare Dad variable Private, I am struggling all day.  and Dad::operator=(other); is what I need. after I call the "dad operator=", my program is going to run well. thanks  a lot, man.

Comment: Yes, he could have left them both out, but i don't really see the educational value in that. Then you don't see what is going on. Yes, you are doing the compilers work for it, but at the same time you see what it does. It is the same as using `(*pointer).member` instead of `->`. It is the same, but more clear. Which is, in my opinion what c++ should be about. Knowing what's happening and should happen but not having to worry about typing so much, or having to declare vtables or whatever.